# Different sizes of lambda expressions in VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda

Out of curiosity, I tested the size of a lamba expression. My first thought was, that they'd be `4` bytes big, like a function pointer. Strangely, the output of my first test was `1`:

```
auto my_lambda = [&]() -> void {};
std::cout << sizeof(my_lambda) << std::endl;
```

Then I tested with some calculations inside the lambda, the output still being `1`:

```
auto my_lambda2 = [&]() -> void {int i=5, j=23; std::cout << i*j << std::endl;};
std::cout << sizeof(my_lambda2) << std::endl;
```

My next idea was kinda random, but the output finally changed, displaying the awaited `4`:

```
auto my_lambda3 = [&]() -> void {std::cout << sizeof(my_lambda2) << std::endl;};
std::cout << sizeof(my_lambda3) << std::endl;
```

At least in Visual Studio 2010. [Ideone still display `1` as the output.](http://ideone.com/sbUkE)
I know of the standard rule, that a lambda expression cannot appear in an unevaluated context, but afaik that only counts for direct lambda use like
`sizeof([&]() -> void {std::cout << "Forbidden." << std::endl;})`
on which VS2010 prompts me with a compiler error.
Anyone got an idea what's going on?

Comment: It is a C++ rule that the size of an object can never be zero.  Your 3rd lambda captured a value, requiring storage.

Comment: @Hans: Shouldn't the second one capture the `std::cout` object? But interesting, I just tested it and it's exactly as you say, 4 bytes per captured value.

Comment: No, it is not a local variable.

Comment: @Hans: Maybe make your comment an answer so I can upvote and accept you? ;)

Comment: Go ahead and write up what you found, accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Hans Passant's comment under the question, the solution was found. My original approach was wrong in the fact that I thought every object would be captured by the lambda, but that isn't the case, only those in the enclosing scope are, and only if they are used.
And for everyone of those captured objects, 4 bytes are used (size of the reference).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio probably doesn't implement lambda objects as functions.  You're probably getting an object back.  Who knows what it looks like.  If you're truly interested you could always look at your variables with a debugger and see what they look like...if it'll let you.